Transforming Infinity norm ball in to 1-norm ball
Is there a way by which we can do some non-linear transformations and convert a 1-norm ball into a $\infty$ norm ball?

The $L^1$-ball is not a hypercube for $n>2$. For instance, in $\mathbb R^3$, it is an octahedron.

Oh my bad! Thanks!

But even then, is it possible to transform from one to the other using some non-linear transformation perhaps?

It’s not clear to me what you are looking for. They are both topological balls, so they are homeomorphic.

I want to construct a transformation that takes us from one to the other.

New correct answer: For any point $x\in\mathbb R^n$, let $r$ be its $L^1$-distance from origin. Consider the ray from the origin to $x$. On this ray, pick the point $y$ at $L^\infty$-distance $r$ from the origin. Consider the map $x\mapsto y$. This is a bijective transformation on $\mathbb R^n$ that maps $L^1$-balls to $L^\infty$-balls of “same radius”.
Old incorrect answer: Let $B_1$ and $B_\infty$ denote the two balls. Pick a point $x \in B_1$ and consider the line joining $x$ and $0$. It intersects $B_\infty$ at two points $y$ and $-y$. Let $y$ be the point on this line that is on the same side of $0$ as $x$. Consider the map $x\mapsto y$. It is clear that this is a bijection from $B_1$ to $B_\infty$.
